# Finding the number of words in each row

Tags: string, r, apply

Let's say that I want to find the number of words in each row of a data frame.
So in the following example, I want to find that the first value in column one
has 3 words, the second value has 4 words, and so on. I assume this is a task 
for one of the apply functions, but i'm having little luck figuring this out.

```
dat = data.frame(one=c("That is Cool",
  "I like my bank", "He likes pizza", "What"))
```

Do I need to work with `strsplit()` or is it better to use the `apply()` function while creating 
a function: `apply(dat, 1, function(x)...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below should do it, assuming all the words are separated by spaces.

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(dat$one), " "), length)
# [1] 3 4 3 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach based on regular expressions. Idea is to remove everything except spaces and compute length of modified string (i.e. number of spaces, so +1 to get number of words):

```
nchar(gsub("[^ ]", "", dat$one)) + 1
# [1] 3 4 3 1
```

Also you could add protection to handle string with spaces at beginning or end:

```
nchar(gsub("[^ ]|^ *| *$", "", dat$one)) + 1
# [1] 3 4 3 1
```

Examples:

```
x <- c(" One two ", "One Two ", " One two")
nchar(gsub("[^ ]", "", x)) + 1
# [1] 4 3 3
sapply(strsplit(x, " "), length)
# [1] 3 2 3
nchar(gsub("[^ ]|^ *| *$", "", x)) + 1
# [1] 2 2 2
```

---

One more safety check: deal with repeated spaces:

```
x <- " One    Two    "
nchar(gsub("[^ ]|^ *| *$", "", gsub(" +", " ", x))) + 1 
# [1] 2
```